# Select duplicate rows in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In my database i create the table:

`| ID |FAILURE | FAMILY_ID | FAILURE_DATE
| 1  |  AAA   | 1         | 2016-06-16 17:22:09.823
| 2  |  BBB   | 2         | 2016-06-16 17:17:09.853
| 3  |  CCC   | 3         | 2016-06-16 17:12:09.853
| 4  |  DDD   | 4         | 2016-06-16 17:07:09.853
| 5  |  AAA   | 2         | 2016-06-16 17:22:09.857
| 6  |  BBB   | 1         | 2016-06-16 17:17:09.857
| 7  |  CCC   | 2         | 2016-06-16 17:12:09.857
| 8  |  DDD   | 3         | 2016-06-16 17:07:09.857
| 9  |  AAA   | 4         | 2016-06-16 17:22:09.857
| 10 |  BBB   | 3         | 2016-06-16 17:17:09.857
| 11 |  CCC   | 2         | 2016-06-16 17:12:09.857
| 12 |  DDD   | 1         | 2016-06-16 17:07:09.857
| 13 |  AAA   | 2         | 2016-06-16 17:22:09.857
| 14 |  BBB   | 1         | 2016-06-16 17:17:09.857
| 15 |  CCC   | 4         | 2016-06-16 17:12:09.857
| 16 |  DDD   | 3         | 2016-06-16 17:07:09.860
| 17 |  AAA   | 4         | 2016-06-16 17:22:09.860
| 18 |  BBB   | 1         | 2016-06-16 17:17:09.860
| 19 |  CCC   | 2         | 2016-06-16 17:12:09.860
| 20 |  DDD   | 3         | 2016-06-16 17:07:09.860`

With this table I need to select how many times each failures appears with each Family in determined time period.

I create the SQL code below:

```
SELECT
    distinct main.id,
    main.FAILURE,
    main.FAMILY,
    main.FAILURE_DATE
FROM
    dbo.tblTest Main
iNNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        tbl.FAILURE,
        tbl.FAMILY,
        COUNT( 1 ) as CNT
    FROM
        DBO.tblTest tbl
    WHERE
        tbl.FAILURE_DATE >= (SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, -45, ( SELECT GETDATE())))
    GROUP BY
        tbl.FAILURE,
        tbl.FAMILY
    HAVING
        COUNT ( 1 ) > 1
) result on result.FAMILY = Main.FAMILY AND result.FAILURE = Main.FAILURE
```

The result is:

`|ID | FAILURE | FAMILY | FAILURE_DATE
|6   | BBB     |  1 | 2016-06-16 17:17:09.857
|14  | BBB     |  1 | 2016-06-16 17:17:09.857
|18  | BBB     |  1 | 2016-06-16 17:17:09.860
|13  | AAA     |  2 | 2016-06-16 17:22:09.857
|5   | AAA     |  2 | 2016-06-16 17:22:09.857
|17  | AAA     |  4 | 2016-06-16 17:22:09.860
|9   | AAA     |  4 | 2016-06-16 17:22:09.857`

So, how get only time the FAILURE and FAMILY?

The greate result should be:

`|ID | FAILURE | FAMILY | FAILURE_DATE
|6   | BBB     |  1 | 2016-06-16 17:17:09.857
|13  | AAA     |  2 | 2016-06-16 17:22:09.857
|9   | AAA     |  4 | 2016-06-16 17:22:09.857`

How I can change my SQL query to get a result like this?

Comment: just group by  FAMILY  and you can get the result

Comment: @Jack, not work.Error: Message 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The 'dbo.tblTest.ID' column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Your logic is very unclear.  Your title suggests something about retrieving duplicates. Then your query also appears to hint at that with the `having` clause.  But there is nothing in the text of your question that really explains that.

Answer (score 2):

It's tough to recreate precise results when you use `DATEADD(MI,-45,GETDATE())`, but I figured 17:17 should work based on the current time, the data, and time of your posting -- you can replace that as you see fit.

Here is a query using a window function via a CTE.

```
DECLARE @TEST TABLE (ID INT, 
                     FAILURE VARCHAR(5),  
                     FAMILY_ID INT,
                     FAILURE_DATE DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @TEST (ID,FAILURE,FAMILY_ID,FAILURE_DATE)
VALUES (1,'AAA',1,'2016-06-16 17:22:09.823'),
       (2,'BBB',2,'2016-06-16 17:17:09.853'),
       (3,'CCC',3,'2016-06-16 17:12:09.853'),
       (4,'DDD',4,'2016-06-16 17:07:09.853'),
       (5,'AAA',2,'2016-06-16 17:22:09.857'),
       (6,'BBB',1,'2016-06-16 17:17:09.857'),
       (7,'CCC',2,'2016-06-16 17:12:09.857'),
       (8,'DDD',3 ,'2016-06-16 17:07:09.857'),
       (9,'AAA',4,'2016-06-16 17:22:09.857'),
       (10,'BBB',3,'2016-06-16 17:17:09.857'),
       (11,'CCC',2,'2016-06-16 17:12:09.857'),
       (12,'DDD',1,'2016-06-16 17:07:09.857'),
       (13,'AAA',2,'2016-06-16 17:22:09.857'),
       (14,'BBB',1,'2016-06-16 17:17:09.857'),
       (15,'CCC',4,'2016-06-16 17:12:09.857'),
       (16,'DDD',3,'2016-06-16 17:07:09.860'),
       (17,'AAA',4,'2016-06-16 17:22:09.860'),
       (18,'BBB',1,'2016-06-16 17:17:09.860'),
       (19,'CCC',2,'2016-06-16 17:12:09.860'),
       (20,'DDD',3,'2016-06-16 17:07:09.860')

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *
           ,COUNT(2) OVER(PARTITION BY FAILURE,FAMILY_ID) AS recordCount
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FAILURE,FAMILY_ID ORDER BY FAILURE_DATE,ID) AS rID
    FROM @TEST
    WHERE FAILURE_DATE >= '2016-06-16 17:17' --DATEADD(MI,-45,GETDATE())
)

SELECT ID, FAILURE, FAMILY_ID, FAILURE_DATE
FROM CTE
WHERE recordCount>1
AND rID=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't have Microsoft SQL Server 2012 now ,please try the codes below:

```
SELECT X.id, X.FAILURE, X.FAMILY, X.FAILURE_DATE 
FROM (
    SELECT
        main.id,
        main.FAILURE,
        main.FAMILY,
        main.FAILURE_DATE,
        ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY main.FAILURE,main.FAMILY ORDER BY main.FAILURE_DATE) AS RM 
    FROM
        dbo.tblTest Main 
) X    
WHERE X.RM=1
```

this is the link of [partition by](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms189461.aspx), may help you

Comment: This won't work; you cannot refer to `RM` in the `WHERE` clause when it is an alias in the `SELECT` clause.  To make this approach work, you will need to wrap everyting from `SELECT` to `FROM dbo.tblTest Main` in a subquery, then put the `WHERE RM=1` as a filter on the subquery. I have edited your answer along these lines.

Comment: @RossPresser than use [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to solve the problem

Comment: CTE or subquery, they're equivalent in this case.